# How do I access a Rigify Control by name (Grouped and linked into scene) with python in 2.79

Tags: python, rigify, groups

I used rigify to generate a control rig over a Basic human Armature.
I then grouped the Armature+Control rig so I could link it into a scene.
In the Scene where it is linked I made the rig a proxy so I could access the controls in pose mode.
Now I want to use a Python script to access specific controls by name and do things to them...

I couldn't figure out how to get to the controls. When I have a control selected say the 'torso', and use the bpy.context.object.name script to print out the name, I just get the name of the rig, not the name of the torso control.
What gives access to the controls inside the group inside the rig ?
[image]
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I used this formula:

```
bpy.data.objects['group_proxy'].pose.bones['torso'].bone.select = True
```